# Is the following code a rock solid way of creating objects from a singleton?

Tags: c#

I've stumbled accross this code in production and I think It may be causing us problems.

```
internal static readonly MyObject Instance = new MyObject();
```

Calling the Instance field twice returns two objects with the same hash code. Is it possible that these objects are different?

My knowledge of the CLI says that they are the same because the hash codes are the same.

Can anyone clarify please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field will only be initialized once, so you'll always get the same object. It's perfectly safe.

Of course, you have to be careful when using static objects from multiple threads. If the object is not thread-safe, you should lock it before accessing it from different threads.

Comment: Locking it is not the object's responsibility, but the caller's. It would be partly, however, if you used lazy initialization.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: "you should lock it before accessing it".

Comment: As pointed out in a now deleted answer, `Instance` *may* contain different objects if it is marked with the [ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx): "A static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute is not shared between threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value."

Comment: 0xA3 - that applies to fields, not classes; and in the example given it isn't marked thus.

Comment: @Philippe: I was just elaborating on your comment about locking.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Right, it was just to add the info that a static *might* contain different values if desired.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is safe - the simplest safe singleton implementation.

As a further point on comparing the hash-code to infer "they're the same object"; since we're talking about reference-types here (singleton being meaningless for value-types), the best way to check if two references point to the same object is:

```
bool isSame = ReferenceEqual(first, second);
```

which isn't dependent on the `GetHashCode()`/`Equals`/`==` implementations (it looks at the reference itself).

Answer (score 5):

It is a guarantee provided by the CLR that this will work properly, even when the class is used by multiple threads.  This is specified in Ecma 335, Partition II, section 10.5.3.3:

There are similar, but more complex, problems when type initialization takes place in a multi-threaded system.  In these cases, for example, two separate threads might start attempting to access static variables of separate
types (A and B) and then each would have to wait for the other to complete initialization.

A rough outline of an algorithm to ensure points 1 and 2 above is as follows:
1. At class load-time (hence prior to initialization time) store zero or null into all static fields of the type.
2. If the type is initialized, you are done.
2.1. If the type is not yet initialized, try to take an initialization lock.
2.2. If successful, record this thread as responsible for initializing the type and proceed to step 2.3.
2.2.1. If not successful, see whether this thread or any thread waiting for this thread to complete already holds
the lock.
2.2.2. If so, return since blocking would create a deadlock. This thread will now see an incompletely initialized
state for the type, but no deadlock will arise.
2.2.3 If not, block until the type is initialized then return.
2.3 Initialize the base class type and then all interfaces implemented by this type.
2.4 Execute the type initialization code for this type.
2.5 Mark the type as initialized, release the initialization lock, awaken any threads waiting for this type to be
initialized, and return.

To be clear, that's the algorithm they propose for a CLR implementation, not your code.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have commented on the rock safety. Here's some more on your reference to hash codes:

The hash codes being the same implies that the two objects **might** be considered **"equal"** - a different concept to "the same". All a hash code really tells you is that, if two objects have **different hash codes**, they are **definitely *not* "equal"** - and therefore by implication definitely not "the same". Equality is defined by the overriding of the `.Equals()` method, and the contract imposed is that if two objects are considered equal by this method, then they must return the same value from their `.GetHashCode()` methods. Two variables are "the same" if their references are equal - i.e. they point to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's static meaning it belongs to the class, and it's readonly, so I cannot be changed after initialization, so yes you will get the same object.

Answer (score 0):

It will work just fine in this case but if you mark the instance with the [ThreadStatic] attribute then inline initialization won't work and you'll have to use something else, like lazy initialization, in which case you don't have to take care if the operations using the singleton are "thread-safe" as the singleton is per thread.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in the fact that the laziness of the initialization
could vary.

Jon Skeet suggests to add an empty static constructor if you care about when
the instance is actually initialized.
In order to avoid exposing in a wrong way I provide you with the link about his
article on the Singleton Pattern.

Your question refers to the Fourth (and suggested) singleton pattern implementation discussed in his article.

Singleton: [singleton implementation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html)

Inside the article you find a link to a discussion on beforefieldinit and laziness of the initialization.

Answer (score -2):

Your assumption that they are the same because the hash codes are the same is incorrect, `GetHashCode()` does a comparison on the fields of your object.

Assuming you didn't overload `Object.Equals`, you can do a simple equals comparison, which is by default a comparison by reference:

```
MyObject a = MyObject.Instance;
MyObject b = MyObject.Instance;

Console.WriteLine(a == b);
```

This will output `True`, by the way, because your singleton implementation is sort of correct. A `static readonly` field is guaranteed to be assigned only once. However, semantically it would be more correct to implement a property with only a get-accessor and use a private static field as a backing store.

Comment: `GetHashCode()` doesn't necessarily do a comparison on the fields of your object.

Comment: The field approach applies to `struct` s, for which singleton is meaningless. For classes, it is the object reference that is hashed by default. A better check would be `ReferenceEquals(a,b)`

Comment: @Marc Gravell: It would be a more fool-proof check, but like I said, *assuming you didn't overload Object.Equals*, `==` will do the same.

Comment: no, my point is that you state: "GetHashCode() does a comparison on the fields of your object.". That is incorrect re *objects* ; it only does that for *value-types*.

Comment: Why would you want to perform a hash of the object reference if the object reference is unique to begin with?